# Setting boundary within MYSQ Query LIKE

Tags: mysql

I need to search products that are B196 not B196Y.   Products are saved within Database in following format

B196 - Hair Band - Pink

```
SELECT * FROM 
sn_unit
where 
product LIKE  'B196%Hair Band%Pink';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add space:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sn_unit
where product LIKE 'B196 %Hair Band%Pink';
```

Answer (score 1):

LIKE can be used to filter out results as well; something like this would be more precise.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sn_unit
WHERE product LIKE 'B196%Hair Band%Pink'
  AND product NOT LIKE 'B196Y%'
;
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are looking your product store with string B196 so, you can search for that string LIKE %B196%. That will find out B196 and you are not looking for B196Y that need to exclude from your query. Thats why exlude it using NOT LIKE %B196y%. This query using AND operator that will return true when string contain only B196.

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM sn_unit
   WHERE product LIKE '%B196%' 
   AND product NOT LIKE '%B196Y%' ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.